# CoreData: Error, there is already another table or index with this name

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Please help me understand this.

1. Why CD has created two additional tables prepending `17` and `19` to them? I didn't create them. My own table name is, `ZJOBLxxxx`
2. How can I get rid of them?
3. How to tackle this error,

`CoreData: sql: ALTER TABLE Z_17JOBLxxxx RENAME TO Z_19JOBLxxxx
[logging] there is already another table or index with this name: Z_19JOBLxxxx in "ALTER TABLE Z_17JOBLxxxx RENAME TO Z_19JOBLxxxx"`

Comment: Do you have some migration configured that might generate this error? Have you tried to delete the tables manually?

Comment: I, indeed, have a new version of my model and the crash occurred while installing on top of an older version of my app. However, I didn't change any attribute or rename. I simply, introduced a new relationship for my table. What's the best practise to tackle this case? I haven't tried delete them manually